# What is wrong with this jQuery for loops inside a loop?

Tags: jquery, loops

the two "for loops" inside the first "for loop" work fine, but the problem comes when I wrap them inside the first loop.

Can anyone see what's wrong with them?

```
jQuery('#rooms').change(function () {

    for (var a = 1; a > 40; a++;) {
        if (jQuery("#rooms").val() == a) {
            var val = a;
            for (var i = 1; i > val; i++) {
                var room = '#room' + i;
                jQuery(room).show();
            }
            for (var i = val + 1; i < 40; i++) {
                var room = '#room' + i;
                jQuery(room).hide();
                jQuery('#r' + i + 'adult, #r' + i + 'child, #room' + i + ' .room-type, #room' + i + ' .room-board, #sr' + i + 'ch1, #sr' + i + 'ch2, #sr' + i + 'ch3, #sr' + i + 'ch4').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

** Thanks, so the problem with that code was the semicolon at the end, and the condition.

What I am trying to achieve is to simplify this code.

Right now this works perfectly for me:

```
                if (jQuery("#rooms").val() == 1) {
                    var val = 1;
                    for ( var i = 1; i < val + 1; i++) {var room = '#room' + i; jQuery(room).show(); }   
                    for ( var i = val + 1; i < 40; i++) {var room = '#room' + i; jQuery(room).hide(); jQuery('#r'+i+'adult, #r'+i+'child, #room'+i+' .room-type, #room'+i+' .room-board, #sr'+i+'ch1, #sr'+i+'ch2, #sr'+i+'ch3, #sr'+i+'ch4').prop('selectedIndex',0); }
            }
            if (jQuery("#rooms").val() == 2) {
                    var val = 2;
                    for ( var i = 1; i < val + 1; i++) {var room = '#room' + i; jQuery(room).show(); }   
                    for ( var i = val + 1; i < 40; i++) {var room = '#room' + i; jQuery(room).hide(); jQuery('#r'+i+'adult, #r'+i+'child, #room'+i+' .room-type, #room'+i+' .room-board, #sr'+i+'ch1, #sr'+i+'ch2, #sr'+i+'ch3, #sr'+i+'ch4').prop('selectedIndex',0); }
            }
            if (jQuery("#rooms").val() == 3) {
                    var val = 3;
                    for ( var i = 1; i < val + 1; i++) {var room = '#room' + i; jQuery(room).show(); }   
                    for ( var i = val + 1; i < 40; i++) {var room = '#room' + i; jQuery(room).hide(); jQuery('#r'+i+'adult, #r'+i+'child, #room'+i+' .room-type, #room'+i+' .room-board, #sr'+i+'ch1, #sr'+i+'ch2, #sr'+i+'ch3, #sr'+i+'ch4').prop('selectedIndex',0); }
            }
```

But I'd like to create a "for loop", so I don't have to repeat those lines until I reach "val() == 40"

** Ahh sorry, I just had to think a little more. Here is the solution:

```
    for ( var x = 1; x < 40; x++) {
            if (jQuery("#rooms").val() == x) {
                    var val = x;
                    for ( var i = 1; i < val + 1; i++) {var room = '#room' + i; jQuery(room).show(); }   
                    for ( var i = val + 1; i < 40; i++) {var room = '#room' + i; jQuery(room).hide(); jQuery('#r'+i+'adult, #r'+i+'child, #room'+i+' .room-type, #room'+i+' .room-board, #sr'+i+'ch1, #sr'+i+'ch2, #sr'+i+'ch3, #sr'+i+'ch4').prop('selectedIndex',0); }
            }
            }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What problem? Give us a little more details to work with ...

Comment: Whats supposed to happen? What is happening?

Comment: sharing the code in jsFiddle is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` can never be greater than `40` and equal to `1` at the same time so will not execute

The code you have placed in your for loop is as follows:

```
for (var a = 1; a > 40; a++;) {
```

There are a number of issues:

- The last semi-colon is forbidden.
- Because `a` can never be greater than `40` and equal to `1` at the same time the loop is broken

Did you mean `a < 40`?

This would lead to something like this:

```
for (var a = 1; a < 40; a++) {
```

Comment: @Amit Joki, Thanks for the edit - now I know how to do that formatting. :-)

Comment: It's all about `Ctrl + K` :)

Comment: Strange. 3 upvotes and  syntax error in the code... The last one semicolon can't be there, of course. `for (var a = 1; a < 40; a++) {`

Comment: It was a copy/paste of the OP code to highlight a mistake - you've just highlighted another mistake.

Comment: @MikeCurry: I know, in the future please fix all message. Changing `>` for `<` if correct, but doesn't solve the problem (the code won't be still working).

Comment: fair point, but hadn't seen it in my code scan; will update answer to include it.

Comment: I was about to comment the same.. You have set the value of a to 1 and are checking that value of a should be greater than 40 which is not true.Hence your code will not execute.

Comment: @MikeCurry: I removed the last semicolon from your answer, now, it will be work correctly. Without logical and syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks, I updated to include the mistaken code, and how the new "correct" loop would look.

Comment: @MikeCurry: I'm not so good in english, but: _The last semi-colon is not required._. Not '_isn't required_', which seems to be optional, but is forbidden.

Comment: I think it is fair either way, but your version is less ambiguous so updated to include - Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, yes that was one of the problems. I've added more info to the original question to see if you can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to do something like this. I have changed the "greater than" to "less than" in the Outer Loop and first Inner Loop in order to make this code work and replaced the outer counter with "5".

```
for (var a = 1; a < 5; a++){
           console.log("Outer Loop a=",a);

                    var val = a;
                    for ( var i = 1; i < val; i++) {
                        console.log("Inner Loop 1 i=",i);
                    }   
                    for ( var i = val + 1; i < 5; i++) {
                        console.log("Inner Loop 2 i=",i);                        
                    }

            }
```